# How to login and access router from remote server using Net::OpenSSH perl package?

Tags: perl, remote-server, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I want to access router from remote server through Perl script.

My Perl script located on one server to access remote server on that remote server have accessibility of all routers means two tier architecture is there.

I have tried creating remote server tunnel and then access to router with username and password but no luck.  What should I do?

**Update:** Following Script

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('RemoteHostIp', port => 3345, user => 'username', password => 'password', 'master_opts' => [-o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"]);

my ($pty, $pid) = $ssh->open2pty(netcat => 'router_ip', 23);

my $telnet = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(-fhopen => $pty,
                                     -prompt => '/.*\$ $/',
                                     -telnetmode => 0,
                                     -cmd_remove_mode => 0,
                                     -output_record_separator => "\r");

$telnet->waitfor(-match => '/username\:/', -errmode => "return") or die "login failed : ".$telnet->lastline;
$telnet->send_wakeup("routerusername");

$telnet->waitfor(-match => '/password\:/', -errmode => "return") or die "login failed : ".$telnet->lastline;
$telnet->send_wakeup("routerpassword");

my @lines = $telnet->cmd(String => "sh ver", Timeout => 10);

print @lines;
$telnet->close;
```

**Output:**

Use of /g modifier is meaningless in split at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/Telnet/Cisco.pm line 756.

|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| This system is for the use of authorized users only.            |
| Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in |
| excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   |
| activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      |
| personnel.                                                      |
|                                                                 |
| In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this   |
| system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities  |
| of authorized users may also be monitored.                      |
|                                                                 |
| Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  |
| and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         |
| evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the |
| evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|

write error: filehandle isn't open at test.pl line 45

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Actually i am not able to creating tunnel. I Mean not able to use telnet in ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the never-released-to-CPAN-but-functional [Net::OpenSSH::Gateway](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-OpenSSH-Gateway) module.

It may be able to find a way to connect to the remote machine through the gateway for you!

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
use Net::OpenSSH::Gateway;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user => $user, ...
                            gateway => { proxy => "ssh://$gateway" });
```

**Update**: it seems (from the code you have posted below as a comment) that actually, you want to **telnet** into the remote routers. `Net::OpenSSH::Gateway` can not handle that as it is designed specifically for connecting to remote SSH servers through proxies or gateways.

Also, it seems port forwarding is disabled in the gateway so you can not just create a tunnel using `Net::OpenSSH::open_tunnel`.

Instead, you will have to find some program in the gateway able to connect to the remote router. For instance, `socat`, `netcat`, `telnet`, etc. and call it through the `Net::OpenSSH` object.

In example:

```
my ($pty, $pid) = $ssh->open2pty(netcat => $host, $port)
  or die "unable to launch remote netcat: " . $ssh->error;

my $telnet = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(-fopen => $pty,
                                     -prompt => '/.*\$ $/',
                                     -telnetmode => 0,
                                     -cmd_remove_mode => 0,
                                     -output_record_separator => "\r");
```

Finally, note that in the code you have posted bellow, you are wrongly using dots (`.`) instead of commas (`,`) in a couple of places.

**Update 2**: error handling code added.

Comment: Thanks for the response,
In gateway attribute how to pass user name and password for gateway server authentication.

Three types of routers are their Cisco, Junipher and Alacatel. Cisco used telnet, Junpher and Alcatel used SSH.

Comment: I have write script used Net::OpenSSH to open tunnel and passed to Net::Telnet::Cisco package to creating new tunnel for router.
But, I got following error.

Channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
write error: filehanlde isn,t open at "pl file with line number".

Comment: Following script:
my $pe = Net::OpenSSH->new("JumpServer", port => 3453, user => 'username', password => 'password');
my($pty, $pid) = $pe->open_tunnel('router_ip', 23);
my $telnet = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(-fopen => $pty, -prompt=>'/.*\$ $/',-telnetmode=>0,-cmd_remove_mode=>0,-output_record_separator=>"\r");
$telnet->waitfor(-match=>'/username\:/'.-errmode=>"return");
$telnet->send_wakeup("routerusername");
$telnet->waitfor(-match=>'/password\:/'.-errmode=>"return");
$telnet->send_wakeup("routerpassword");
my @lines = $telnet->cmd(String=>"sh ver", Timeout=>10);
print @lines;
$telnet->close;

Comment: @user3213879: paste the script and the errors you get exactly, unedited, on your original post properly quoted. Otherwise it is impossible to follow what is going on.

Comment: @Thribhuwan: I have added error checking into my post code. Probably `netcat` is not available on the gateway. You will have to look there for a similar program (`socat`, `telnet`, etc.) and use it instead. Otherwise, if some scripting language (`perl`, `python`, `ruby`, etc.) is available you could use it to implement your own `netcat` clone.

Comment: I have added error handling code line or die "unable to launch remote netcat: " . $ssh->error;

But still I getting same error : write error: filehandle isn't open at test.pl line 43 [Line : my @lines = $telnet->cmd(String => "sh ver", Timeout => 10);]

Comment: it is a time consuming and i am new with perl for implementing own netcat. is their any other better way or package to connect with remote server.

Comment: @Thribhuwan: how do you connect to the remote machine by hand, from the command line?

Comment: I have connect through putty using ssh command.
example : ssh -l username remoteip
then press enter after that to ask password:

Comment: I have updated output. when i run the perl script through command line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102447/discussion-between-thribhuwan-and-salva).